# How can I decrease the duration of each .ts chunk for m3u8 in AWS MediaConvert?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-live-streaming, m3u8, aws-media-convert

I'm looking through the documentation and the presets file located here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/apireference/presets.html

Currently, my ts files have duration of 5 seconds. How can I split this even more? For example: 5 ts files with 1 second for each ts file of 5 seconds. Or 2 ts files of 2.5 seconds for each.

I would think that I just need to configure one of the presets above but I can't find one that explicitly says anything about it.

Answer (score 3):

Segment length for ts chunks using the API can be configured under the **HlsGroupSettings** using the attribute/parameter called **segmentLength**[1].

Please note that this would be set at an output group level so either in the job-template or in the base settings if you were sending a Mediaconvert job using the API

== Documentation ==

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/apireference/jobs.html#jobs-prop-hlsgroupsettings-segmentlength

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to generate HLS output in this scenario. You can manage the length of the segment by configuring `Segment Length(sec)` parameter in MediaConvert's HLS output configuration. You also need to make sure that the segment length is the multiple of key frame interval `GOP size` to get accurate segment duration. If not, the transcoder will round-up the segment to the nearest value(eg:- 2 sec GOP Size for 6 sec segment length). The best option here is to create profile template with your required configuration and use the template for triggering the job.